# Sencha touch, Android version layout issue

Tags: android, css, sencha-touch, extjs

I have an app which is doing wonderful.

Except for phones with Android version 2.3.3 and under on it. When changing pages, instead of current page sliding away and new page entering, the current page stays and the new page enters, causing overlapping layout issues.

layout issue screenshot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/44bqr.jpg

Anyone has a clue on what is going on?

Comment: If no one has specifically encountered this problem, subsequently resolved it **and** uses SO, you must include code that may be the cause of this.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue earlier I resolved this issue by creating object for the panel on demand and activating the item on demand means where we have to show that panel by using `setActiveItem()`